# React: group by multidimensional array object by value in component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

How to group multidimensional array objects by value in the component.

I need to group array by page and get the text for every page. I tray to use the map and reduce it but don't get good results. I work on `react-native` project. JS function groups doesn't work for some reason.

What is the best way to write code for this array?

I have this array:

```
[
  {
    number: 1,
    englishName: 'Name 1',
    items: [
      {
        text: 'Some text',
        page: 1,
      },
      {
        text: 'Some text',
        page: 1,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    number: 2,
    englishName: 'Name 2',
    items: [
      {
        text: 'Some text',
        page: 2,
      },
      {
        text: 'Some text',
        page: 2,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    number: 3,
    englishName: 'Name 3',
    items: [
      {
        text: 'Some text',
        page: 3,
      },
      {
        text: 'Some text',
        page: 4,
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

I need an array like this

```
[
  {
    'page 1': [
      {
        text: 'Some text',
        englishName: 'Name 1',
      },
      {
        text: 'Some text',
        englishName: 'Name 2',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    'page 2': [
      {
        text: 'Some text',
        englishName: 'Name 2',
      },
      {
        text: 'Some text',
        englishName: 'Name 2',
      },
    ],
  },
  ....
]
```

Comment: Please show your attempt to implement the requirement. Also the resulting structure looks weird. Are you sure you need an array of objects having single key not a single object with multiple keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this will work for you.

This will give you an object:

```
const allPages = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    curr.items.forEach((page) => {
        var pageKey = `page ${page.page}`
        if(!acc[pageKey]){
            acc[pageKey] = []
        }
        acc[pageKey].push({ text: page.text, englishName: curr.englishName })
    })
    return acc
}, {})
```

You can convert that object into an array as well:

```
const finalArr = Object.entries(allPages).map(([page, array]) => {
    return {
        [page]: array
    }
})
```

See example:

```js
var array = [{
        "number": 1,
        "englishName": "Name 1",
        "items": [
            {
                "text": "Some text",
                "page": 1,
            },
            {
                "text": "Some text",
                "page": 1,
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "number": 2,
        "englishName": "Name 2",
        "items": [
            {
                "text": "Some text",
                "page": 2,
            },
            {
                "text": "Some text",
                "page": 2,
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "number": 3,
        "englishName": "Name 3",
        "items": [
            {
                "text": "Some text",
                "page": 3,
            },
            {
                "text": "Some text",
                "page": 4,
            }
        ]
    }
]



const allPages = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
   curr.items.forEach((page) => {
   var pageKey = `page ${page.page}`
   if(!acc[pageKey]){
     acc[pageKey] = []
   }
   acc[pageKey].push({ text: page.text, englishName: curr.englishName })
   })
     return acc
}, {})
    
    
    
const finalArr = Object.entries(allPages).map(([page, array]) => {
    return {
    [page]: array
    }
})
    
    
console.log(allPages)
console.log(finalArr)
```